# Unable to find a way to break a sequence

Tags: python, list, function, collatz

I wanted the sequence to break (not to print any sequence) if the length of the name is greater than the length of the sequence but I couldn't find a way:
I know that the print(List) statement shouldn't be there but i don't know where to put it.

```
x=input("enter name")
def seq():
   q=1
   n=int(input("enter number"))
   List=[n]
   while q<n:
       if (n % 2):
           n = 3*n + 1
           List.append(n)
       else:
           n=n//2
           List.append(n)
   while len(List)<len(x):
       break

   print(List)
seq()
```

Comment: you may just be looking for `if (insert your condition here): return`; `break` will only escape the innermost loop (`while` in your case)

Comment: What's the point of a loop that only contains `break`? It will never do anything.

Comment: Just remove the second `while` loop and change the first to `while q < n and len(List) < len(x):`

Comment: If you do `List.append(n)` in both the `if` and `else`, take it out of the condition and just do it in one place after them.

Comment: @Mark that actually helps a little but i still have a problem. I want the code to stop printing the sequence when the while statement isn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by replacing when with If Condition and also you can try passing x value to fun:

```
def seq():
   q=1
   n=int(input("enter number"))
   List=[n]
   while q<n:
       if (n % 2):
           n = 3*n + 1
           List.append(n)
       else:
           n=n//2
           List.append(n)
   If (len(List)<len(x)):
       break

   print(List)

x=input("enter name")
seq()
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
x=input("enter name")
def seq():
   q=1
   n=int(input("enter number"))
   List=[n]
   while q<n:
       if (n % 2):
           n = 3*n + 1
           List.append(n)
       else:
           n=n//2
           List.append(n)
       if len(List)<len(x):
           break

   print(List)
seq()
```

Comment: What's the change, and why? Edit your answer.